# Jquery jplayer in IE (internet explorer) playlist demo and implementation

Tags: jquery

I recently implemented a version of the  JPlayer playlist for part of a website.  Works fine on firefox, safari, chrome, but doesn't work at all in IE.  The error for IE specifically says Object doesn't support this property or method.  Just for kicks I went back to the site where I downloaded the demo from and sure enough that playlist demo doesn't function in IE as well...  When I open up the show JPlayer inspector it also doesn't work, saying

This jPlayer instance is running in your browser where:
 jPlayer's html solution is not required
 jPlayer's flash solution is not required

No solution is currently active. jPlayer needs a setMedia().

I have read some similar issues to this.  Tried setting up the swf path to /js/jPlayer.swf etc... But still not having any luck.

Here's the demo site http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is late in the game, but did anyone ever find a reason for this?